# Question about denominator of difference quotient establishing Taylor Approximation of a function.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, polynomials, taylor-expansion

I'm working through *Spivak's Calculus* and currently I'm working on the polynomial approximation chapter (Ch.20). In establishing that the Taylor polynomial approximates our function $f$ at a point ($f(x)$) we are presented with the following theorem:

[image]

The numerator makes sense to me because we want to see the difference between out function, $f$, and the Taylor approximation of it as we approach our given point. But what is the purpose of the denominator and why do we raise it to its respective power of $n$ ? I somewhat get the idea of it is showing that the difference between $f(x) - P_{n,a}(s)$ is becoming smaller at a faster rate than $x \to a$. But I guess I never really sat back to ask why it needs to be expressed in a ratio form as well as why do we need to raise it to whichever power of $n$ that our Taylor polynomial is.Just for completeness I do understand using L'Hopital to obtain said limit, but the reasoning in expressing it as such is what I'm stuck with.

I should add that the motivation for this comes from the example they provide in the text using $e^{x}$ and it's respective Taylor Polynomial comparing the difference at first to $x$ and then $x^{2}$. He doesn't completely explain the rationale behind this "compensation term":

[image]

TL;DR:  Why do we express this approximation as a difference quotient and why do we need to raise to a respective power of $n$ ?

Comment: Which is better? $f(x)-p(x)\to 0$ as $x\to a,$ or $(f(x)-p(x))/(x-a)^n \to 0$ as $x\to a?$

Comment: To build off of what you're saying, so if we divide it by something that $\to 0$ fast, that would mean the quotient which is even "smaller" goes $\to 0$ "fast", that is faster than the denominator?.......edit:  I liked you're first analogy better @zhw.

Comment: The second $\to 0$ is a much better result than the first $\to 0.$